# Hibernate Throwing Max Size Attribute Is Mandatory Exception

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm just getting started trying to use Hibernate to create a PostgreSQL database but keep getting this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: max size attribute is mandatory
```

It happens when I run my main method on the line where I try to build a session factory but I can't find anything about this exception anywhere online.  I'm wondering anyone has any ideas on what could be causing this.

Main Class:

```
package com.package.ingestor;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student user = new Student();
        user.setStudentId(1);
        user.setStudentName("Bri Guy");
        user.setStudentAge(32);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Hibernate Object:

```
package com.bossanova.ingestor;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id"})})
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", length=11, nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Integer studentId;

    @Column(name = "name", length=20, nullable=true)
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name="age", length=5, nullable=true)
    private Integer studentAge;

    public Student() { }

    public Student(Integer studId, String studName, Integer studAge) {
        this.studentId = studId;
        this.studentName = studName;
        this.studentAge = studAge;
    }

    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public Integer getStudentAge() {
        return studentAge;
    }

    public void setStudentAge(Integer studentAge) {
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student= Id: " + this.studentId + ", Name: " + this.studentName + ", Age: " + this.studentAge;
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.bossanova.ingestor.Student"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this for me by switching my Maven dependency from hibernate-agroal to hibernate-core.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using hibernate-agroal add <type>pom</type> to your dependency